# Reservation is trying to change the price of a room

Tags: bookings, scams, booking.com

Over a month ago my girlfriend and I booked a hotel in Mazunte for 300 pesos a night on booking.com. The booking did not require a credit card and and said the price was to be paid in full at the property. Yesterday, 4 days before our booking, we received a Whats App message from the property saying they made a mistake and we will now have to pay 500 pesos a night when we arrive. In the What's App message they included pictures and a Google maps location that are different than the ones on booking.com.

We sent the a message back saying we will only pay for the original agreed upon price, but they haven't replied. Is this kind of behavior allowed under booking.com's terms and how can we ensure they don't try to change us the inflated price when we arrive at the property?

Comment: better contact booking.com customer service.

Comment: You assume the message was genuinely from the property. It is possible that someone at the property leaked your details to a scammer who is now trying to trick you out of your money, unknown to the property manager or to booking.com

Comment: I do think it is actually from the property because we got a message from the property on booking.com saying to check our What's App.

Comment: Then you definitely should contact booking.com because it seems like the property is trying to bypass the 'official' payment & communication systems and is scamming both you and booking.com

Comment: Prediction: they will not be on booking.com for long. I do suspect you will need to find another place to stay, and booking.com may help.

Comment: Is WhatApp a typical way for hotels to communicate with guests in Mexico?

Answer (score 2):

Contact booking.com.   They were very helpful resolving my issue in Spain his month.